# Problem displaying dynamic data in an array in Laravel blade view using Javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, associative-array, laravel-blade

Working on a Laravel application whereby I have some data in an array. The data is a collection of associative arrays whereby each array has an **identity number** and a **collection of policy codes** in it. Am fetching the data and displaying to the blade. In the view I have partitioned in **2 columns (using bootstrap grid system)**. On the left column (col-md-4) am looping through the variable and displaying the identity number which **works fine**. On the right column I have a table whereby am supposed to display the respective policy code depending on the state of identity_no.

I want to achieve a functionality whereby when the user clicks or hovers over a particular identity number, the respective policy codes should be displayed on the right column (col-md-8)in the table tbody tag. The same should be repeated for subsequent identity numbers (should only display after the identity number has been clicked or hovered on).

**Array collection that is stored in a variable called asm**

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "identity_no" => "71360"
    "policy_code" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "IL2***********"
      1 => "IL2***********"
      2 => "IL2***********"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "identity_no" => "68181"
    "policy_code" => array:3 [▼
      0 => "IL2**********"
      1 => "IL2***********"
      2 => "IL2***********"
      3 => "IL2***********"
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "identity_no" => "53983"
    "policy_code" => array:4 [▼
      0 => "IL2*************"
      1 => "IL2*************"
      2 => "IL2*************"
      3 => "IL2*************"
      4 => "IL2*************"
      5 => "IL2*************"
    ]
  ]
]
```

**Layout on the view**

```
<div class="row">
  <!-- lEFT column -->
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <div id="MainMenu">
    <div class="list-group panel">
      <!-- Level 1 -->
      @foreach($asm as $a)
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-primary" > Identity No: {{ $a['identity_no'] }} </a>
      @endforeach
      <!-- END level 1-->
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END left column-->

<!-- Right column-->
<div class="col-md-8">
      <table id="summary-table">
          <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Policy Codes</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td> <!-- Add dynamic policy codes--></td>
            </tr> 
          </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is the issue you are facing while achieving this?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz Am not sure how to display the policy codes in the table after a particular identity number is clicked or hovered on using Javascript

Comment: @MayankPandeyz What`s your suggestion about it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this(tested on my local and found it working):

```
<script>
    var data;
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        data = {!! json_encode($asm) !!};
    });
    $(document).on("mouseenter", "a", function() {
        var policyCodes = '';
        var identityNo = $(this).attr('id');
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if(identityNo == data[i]['identity_no']) {
                for(var j = 0;j < data[i]['policy_code'].length;j++){
                    policyCodes += '<td>' + data[i]['policy_code'][j] + '</td>';
                }
            }

        }
        console.log(policyCodes);
        $('#summary-table tbody tr').html(policyCodes);
    });
</script>


@foreach($asm as $a)
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-primary" id="{{ $a['identity_no'] }}" > Identity No: {{ $a['identity_no'] }} </a>
                @endforeach
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: You can omit that console statement, I have included that for testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks for help,, Just some clarification.. What about the identity number,, do I populate it using AJAX as we have done with policy codes.. ?

Comment: Yes, You are absolutely right Martin, Actually, I just forgot to mention that part of code:

Comment: @foreach($asm as $a)
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-primary" id="{{ $a['identity_no'] }}" > Identity No: {{ $a['identity_no'] }} </a>
                @endforeach

Comment: I have added that in my answer... Thanks :)

Comment: Sure Martin :)... Would be looking for your feedback

Comment: Thanks alot,, it works fine,, Had really struggled with it,, am a Js Beginner.. Just one last question how can I display the policyCodes in a vertical manner inside the table instead of horizontal order..

Comment: Hey, Glad to hear that my solution worked for you. You can play around with <br> tags in "policyCodes += '<td>' + data[i]['policy_code'][j] + '</td>';" as per your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

try this! I know javascript only so the solution is in pure javascript and jquery I have merged both hover and click event on the button. Hope this may help

```js
asm = [{
    identity_no: '1',
    policy_code: "bla bla111111111"
}, {
    identity_no: "2",
    policy_code: "bla bla2222222"
}, {
    identity_no: "3",
    policy_code: "bla bla3333"
}];

function btns() {
    var btn = $("<button class='tags' id=" + asm[i].identity_no + ">" + asm[i].identity_no + "</button>");
    $(btn).attr("data-search", asm[i].identity_no)
    $(btn).appendTo("#buttons")
}

$('#buttons').on('click mouseover', 'button', function() {
    console.log('click on', $(this).attr('id'));
    var a = asm.filter(x => x.identity_no === $(this).attr('id')).map(x => x.policy_code);
    console.log("found!--", a)
        // show this on other side of col
});

for (i = 0; i < asm.length; i++) {

    btns();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="buttons"></div>
```